# What is the accepted practice for custom serialization in jackson?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm trying to write custom serialization for an object in jackson and there seem to be many options, I'm wondering if one is generally preferred over the others.

I've read about `JsonSerializableWithType`, and its deprecated sibling `JsonSerializable`. This seems good, since it doesn't require users of the class to register `Module`s in their `ObjectMapper`s. However I can't seem to resolve `JsonSerializableWithType` or find any examples of its usage. The fasterxml page that talks about it seems dated as well.

The other option seems to be external serialization with `JsonSerializer`s. I've read about `@JsonSerialize`, but can't tell if it's better/worse/older/newer than `JsonSerializable`.

Is there a compelling argument for either one of those over the other? Or is registering a `Module` to an `ObjectMapper` the most accepted way?

Comment: Look at things like https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short: this really comes down to your personal preferences, as well as whether you have access to source code of value objects.

The difference is between in-built (implement `JsonSerializable`) or external serializers (annotation or module); as well as internal (annotation) vs external (module) association/registration of serializers.

So I would not say there is universal preference: each works, is supported, and (in my opinion) makes sense for some cases.

Some developers prefer external approach because it allows value classes to have no dependencies to Jackson types: when implementing `JsonSerializable`, for example, you add a hard dependency to `jackson-databind`. With `@JsonSerialize` annotation you get a weaker dependency to `jackson-annotations`, whereas with module approach there is no direct dependency at all.

There are potential benefits to implementing `JsonSerializable`, in that this allows all details of the value class and its handling (including serialization) to be encapsulated within class definition.
Some would also consider that a downside; it depends on your view on proper OOP practices vs practicality of development.

Now: in some cases, such as when supporting 3rd party libraries, your choices are limited to external module, or use of mix-in annotations.
For your own value types you can pick and choose.

Comment: @JsonSerialize is the way I ended up going. Do you have any examples of JsonSerializableWithType working? I've not been able to find any.

Comment: Just realized something; `JsonSerializableWithType` was only used with Jackson 1.x, and method `serializeWithType` was merged in base `JsonSerializer` for 2.0. But it is implementated by "node" types like, say, `ArrayNode` and `ObjectNode` within `jackson-databind`; as well as `RawValue` helper type.

Comment: awesome, I had a suspicion something like that happened, I just couldn't find it documented anywhere.